# Continuous loop redirect when posting to Facebook via API

Tags: php, facebook, yii

Here is my code:

```
$app_id = '1xx66xxxxx337499';
        $app_secret = '4545daed40xxxxxx5d6649c82d3e983';
        $redirect_url = 'http://localhost/linkmo/site/registerfacebookuser';

        $status = "Testing the waters";
        $description = "here is product description";
        $link = 'http://demo.microgigz.com/linkmo';
        $name = "Product name";

        Yii::import("application.extensions.facebooksdk.Facebook");
        $config = array();
        $config['appId'] = $app_id;
        $config['secret'] = $app_secret;
        $fb = new Facebook($config);

        $user_facebook_information = UserSocials::model()->findbyAttributes(array('user_id' => Yii::app()->user->id));
        $current_access_token = $user_facebook_information->fb_access_token;
        $facebook_id = $user_facebook_information->facebook_id;

        $params = array(
            // this is the main access token (facebook profile)
            "access_token" => $current_access_token,
            "message" => $status,
            "link" => $link,
            "name" => $name,
            "caption" => "www.linkmo.com",
            "description" => $description
        );

        $ret = $fb->api('/' . $facebook_id . '/feed', 'POST', $params);
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('posted_to_fb', 'Your message has been posted to facebook successfully!');
        $this->redirect('dashboard');
```

Everything is valid in terms of access tokens etc and I am successfully able to post on facebook via API but the problem his whenever I use the  `$this->redirect('dashboard');` instead of 1 status it posts 10+ statuses and does not redirect to dashboard.

Can anyone explain what is the reason?

Comment: I do not think that the error occurs in this code. What controller/action are you using? And you defined `$redirect_url` but do not use it - is it necessary?

Comment: Yes I have defined redirect url but currently not using it, it will be used to re-authenticate the user when token expires after 60 days. $redirect_url is irrelevant to the error here. Any other error you can identify?

Comment: When I don't use $this->redirect('dashboard') only one status is posted then and everything works fine. I think facebook ouath object is being conflicted with Yii controller object. Is it the case?

Comment: That is why I asked for more code. What is your controller, what is your action and maybe how about your url manager? Because redirect works not this way. Try an ``url` or `controller/action`. Your `dashboard` should link to `controller/dashboard` - right?